# Java Simple Client Server application

Tags: java, loops, server, client

Im sorry I am coding 12 hours now and now I have a "brainlag".

I made a little Client Server programm.

Client:

```
public void send(String send) {
    DataOutputStream out;
    Socket client;

        try {
            client = new Socket("192.168.0.138", port);
            out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            out.writeChars(send + '\n');
            Thread.sleep(100L);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Can't connect to Server!");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println("Cant sleep!");
        }
}
```

Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int port = 5000;
    String cIn;
    System.out.println("Running on Port 5000");
    ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket client;
    BufferedReader inFromClient;
    while (true) {
        client = sock.accept();
        inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        cIn = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("" + cln);
    }
}
```

Now my question. How can i make it that my string (data) is sending in a loop to the server while I input a new data.

If a make a normal while loop, my string is sending permanently to the server. If i change my String it doesn't matter.
I would make it that if i change my String, that the new String is sending to the server.

I'm sorry for my bad english. I hope you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

how about sending the data with a new thread whichs sends the data in a loop. when you input some new data interupt the old thread and start a new one and so on?

Answer (score 0):

If I resume:
- you need a console app (or window/awt/swing ...) or main client app which take a String, and sometimes change this String.
- this String must be sent by your function "send", continuously, with the last String

I propose you:

1 - to fix the loop (1 sec, 2, sec, x seconds ?)

2 - to use a share variable (in critical section, or synchronized), your main client app writes it, and changes it when you want, and your "send" function read it every x seconds and sends it.

Your client could look like that:

```
// SHARED VARIABLE
static String warning="";
final static Object warning_sync=new Object();

// Alert function 
class Thread_alert extends Thread 
    {
    // YOUR CODE
    public void send(String send) {
        DataOutputStream out;
        Socket client;
        int port=80;

            try {
                client = new Socket("192.168.0.138", port);
                out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                out.writeChars(send + '\n');
                Thread.sleep(100L);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Can't connect to Server!");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println("Cant sleep!");
            }
    }


    public Thread_alert()
        {
        super();
        }

    public void run() 
        {
        while (true)
            {
            // WHAT YOU HAVE TO DO

            synchronized(warning_sync)
                {
                System.err.println("WARN: "+warning);
                send(warning);
                }

            // Sleep 5 seconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            // while (true)
        }
        // public void run()
}
// class Thread_alert



public void console_client () 
{
// START THE THREAD
Thread_alert lethread=new Thread_alert();
lethread.start();   

// INPUT LOOP
 Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
 String line;

 while ((line=s.nextLine())!=null)
     {
    System.out.println("STRING:'"+line+"'"); 

    // Fix the warning
    synchronized(warning_sync)
        {
        warning=line;
        }

    // bonus
    // IF STOP: STOP
    if (warning.equals("STOP")) 
        {
        lethread.stop();
        break;
        }
     } 
    // while ((line=s.nextLine())!=null)

 // safe
 s.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a bufferedReader close at the end of the while loop.

```
while (true) {
    client = sock.accept();
    inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    cIn = inFromClient.readLine();
    System.out.println("" + cln);
    inFromClient.close() //add this
}
```